# MVVM light Silverlight multiple Selection list box initial selection on page load

Tags: c#, silverlight, list, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM light and have a list box with multiple selection. In my Mainpage.xaml I have

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"  Margin="15,15,18,0" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="100" />
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs I have (I do not want to use dependency property for some reason).

```cs
MainPage()
{
    ListBox1.SelectionChanged = new SelectionChangedEventHandler(ListBox1_SelectionChanged);
}

void ListBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
 var listBox = sender as ListBox;
 var viewModel = listBox.DataContext as MainViewModel;
 viewModel.SelectedItems.Clear();
 foreach (string item in listBox.SelectedItems)
     viewModel.SelectedItems.Add(item);
}
```

and this works fine and binds to my MainViewModel. But When the page is loaded I want the first item of the the collection items to be selected by default. Please let me know how to implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using the ListBox's `Loaded` event and then bind to the first item in the collection:

```
MainPage()
{
    ListBox1.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler( OnListBox1Loaded );
    ListBox1.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(ListBox1_SelectionChanged);
}

private void OnListBox1Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    // make sure the selection changed event doesn't fire
    // when the selection changes
    ListBox1.SelectionChanged -= MyList_SelectionChanged;

    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    e.Handled = true;

    // re-hook up the selection changed event.
    ListBox1.SelectionChanged += MyList_SelectionChanged;
}
```

**Edit**

If you can not use the `Loaded` event, then you'll need to create another property in your Model that will hold the item you want selected and then assign that property to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox`.

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  private ObservableCollection<SomeObject> _items;
  public ObservableCollection<SomeObject> Items
  {
    get { return _items; }
    set
    {
        _items = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged( "Items" );
    }
  }

  private SomeObject _selected;
  public SomeObject  Selected
  {
    get { return _selected; }
    set
    {
        _selected = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged( "Selected" );
    }
  }

  public void SomeMethodThatPopulatesItems()
  {
    // create/populate the Items collection

    Selected = Items[0];
  }

  // Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged excluded for brevity

}
```

**XAML**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Selected}"/>
```

By having another property that holds the currently selected item, you also have access in your Model to that item as well whenever the selected item is changed by the user.

Comment: What is MyList_SelectionChanged. Assuming ListBox1_SelectionChanged when i try to do that at the line ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; I get "ArgumentOutOfRange Exception" Since the ItemsSource of ListBox1 is not yet loaded

Comment: The error is because the binding hasn't occurred yet; see my edit for using a more MVVM approach that uses another property to hold the currently selected item from the `ListBox`.

Comment: I have another small question for you. When the contents of the list box changes based on the some other control changes on the page. How can you retain the selected value to first element.

Comment: To the top left of all answers is an up/down arrow; click up if it helped, down if it was horrid. Any answer you feel helped you, just vote up. If you asked the question, click the check-mark to accept an answer as the most helpful answer to your question. Also, see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: You have 12 now, so you should be good. Enjoy SO! (StackOverflow)

Comment: huh now it tells me voting up requires atleast 15 reputations. Not sure whts wrong